# Amazon API ItemLookup response parsing

Tags: xml, amazon-web-services, xml-parsing

In my web application doing Amazon API 'ItemLookup' requests, getting response, for example I want get all ASINs of "iPhone 7" available on amazon.com, my request looks like this:

```
public class Application {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<String> foundASINs = new ArrayList<>();
        Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<>();
        params.put("Operation", "ItemSearch");
        params.put("ResponseGroup", "ItemIds");
        params.put("Keywords", "iphone 7");
        params.put("SearchIndex", "Wireless");
        AwsRequest request = new AwsRequest();
        String res="";
        try {
            request.getRequest(params);
```

and AwsRequest class:

```
public Document getRequest (Map<String, String> params) throws IOException, NoSuchAlgorithmException, InvalidKeyException, ParserConfigurationException, SAXException {
        params.put("Service", "AWSECommerceService");
        params.put("AssociateTag", ASSOCIATE_TAG);
        params.put("Version", "2016-09-27");

        SignedRequestsHelper helper = SignedRequestsHelper.getInstance(ENDPOINT, AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID, AWS_SECRET_KEY);
        String requestUrl = helper.sign(params);
        DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        DocumentBuilder db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();
        doc = db.parse(requestUrl);
        return doc;
    }
```

so I'm getting response as XML document. 
Everything ok, but I wonder why I'm getting maximum 10 ASINs? If I check TotalResults property of document, there must be 10000+ results, but in response I can see only 10? How I can get others?

Answer (score 0):

Its part of the amazon API restrictions that you only receive 10 items per page with a max of ten pages.  so the top 100 but you can alter your searches to get more but not without extra searches.